# Make Parallel list of checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, checkbox

I am adding a bunch of checkboxes to a form using appendchild in HTML using Javascript. I can add spaces between them by appending textnodes, but how do I make a parallel list from them, like one checkbox on left, other on right. Something similar to this.

```
Checkbox1        Checkbox2
Checkboxes3      Check4
```

And so on.

Comment: You can use a table for that.

Comment: @NadeemAfana Which isn't the best practice. `float`ed elements would be a better idea here.

Comment: @Doorknob Can you give/show an example?

Comment: @Ritwick You could use the CSS `.checkbox-container { float: left; width: {something}px }`, and add containers around all of the checkboxes.

Comment: @Doorknob I haven't really used CSS much. Can you link me to an example or just give me a simple one with two checkboxes here? Thanks

Comment: What is the context of the textboxes?  If this is for tabular data, use a table.  If it's not for data, then use floats.  Use correct elements when you need to, otherwise you'll end up in div hell.

Comment: @zero298 I am making a website to order pizza and every pizza has around 20 different toppings which I need to populate as checkboxes dynamically. They are all bunched as of now, that why I want to have them in order, probably two or three rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing that, with floated divs being the easiest.

```
<doctype html>
<html>
   <header>
      <title>Sample floated stuff</title>
      <style>
         .cb-div {
         width: 33%;
         display:block;
         float: left;
         }
      </style>
   </header>
   <body>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test1" type="checkbox"> Test 1
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test2" type="checkbox"> Test 2
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test3" type="checkbox"> Test 3
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test4" type="checkbox"> Test 4
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test5" type="checkbox"> Test 5
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test6" type="checkbox"> Test 6
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test7" type="checkbox"> Test 7
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test8" type="checkbox"> Test 8
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test9" type="checkbox"> Test 9
      </label>
      </span>
      <span class="cb-div">
      <label>
      <input name="test10" type="checkbox"> Test 10
      </label>
      </span>
      <div style="clear:both">
         And clear:both breaks you free of floating
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a table, add your check boxes then set border to none. It will appear in the correct format and will not look like it's in a table.